# Separate odd even from string

Tags: java, string, loops

The below is the question:

Get comma separated String of numbers from user and print the set of odd numbers and even numbers.

sample input:

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Sample output:

Odd Numbers:

1,3,5,7,9

Even Numbers:

2,4,6,8,10

Sample input:

20,30,40

Sample output:

Even Numbers:

20,30,40

My code:

```
class OddEv{
public static void main(String args[]){
    String s;
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    s=in.nextLine();
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        if(s.charAt(i)%2==0){
            System.out.print(s.charAt(i));

        }

       if(s.charAt(i)%2!=0){
             System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
       }
    }
```

but I am not getting the right answer. What **changes**  should I bring to get the right output according to the question

actually I don't know java very well so I don't know what to do here

Comment: *"but I am not getting the right answer"* What answer *are* you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this simple solution, without using any other concepts like `regex`. For this, you can split your string and store it in a string array, and than iterating over an array you can check whether the number is odd or even. Following code will store all the even and odd numbers from your string into the array named `even` and `odd`.

```
String s = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";

int even[] = new int[10];
int odd[] = new int[10];
String ar[] = s.split(",");
int j=0,k=0,oddChecker=0,evenChecker=0;
for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
    if(Integer.parseInt(ar[i])%2 == 0){
        even[j] = Integer.parseInt(ar[i]);
                ++j;
        evenChecker = 1;

    }   
    else{
        odd[k] = Integer.parseInt(ar[i]);
        ++k;
    oddChecker = 1;
    }

}


if(oddChecker == 0){
    System.out.println("even");
    System.exit(0);
}

if(evenChecker == 0){
    System.out.println("odd");
    System.exit(0);
}



System.out.println("Even numbers:");

for(int i=0;i<j;i++){
if(i!=j-1){
        System.out.print(even[i]+",");
}
else{
    System.out.print(even[i]);
}
}
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Odd numbers:");

for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
if(i!=k-1){
        System.out.print(odd[i]+",");
}
else{
    System.out.print(odd[i]);
}
}
```

> **Output:**
>
> Even numbers:
>   2,4,6,8,10
>
> Odd numbers:
>   1,3,5,7,9

Don't forget to convert String to Integer when checking the condition and adding numbers to arrays. For that I've used `Integer.parseInt(your_string)`.

Comment: the problem in ur code is that the output format...there are no commas in betwween , the number series should come next line after "Even Numbers" or "Odd Numbers",If the series of numbers only contains either even or odd then only that ("either even or odd" )output should be on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

use two `ArrayList` of `Integer` for odds and evens, and change `String s` to `String []s` then use `userInput.split(",")` to separate numbers. parse strings in s to integer using `Integer.parseInt(str)` method then use if statement to determine number is odd or even and add them to arraylists.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s[];
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    s = in.nextLine().split(",");
    ArrayList<Integer> odds = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> evens = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String item : s) {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(item);
        if (number % 2 == 0) {
            evens.add(number);
        } else {
            odds.add(number);
        }
    }
}
```

---

you can use following code to print results in output:

```
System.out.println("Even Numbers:");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(evens.toArray()).replaceAll("[\\p{Ps}\\p{Pe}]", ""));
System.out.println("Odd Numbers:");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(odds.toArray()).replaceAll("[\\p{Ps}\\p{Pe}]", ""));
```

---

**sample input:**

```
10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
```

**sample output:**

```
Even Numbers:
10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20
Odd Numbers:
11, 13, 15, 17, 19
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this solves your problem

```
 public class CommaSeperatedNum {
        public static void main(String args[]){
        String s;
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        s=in.nextLine();

    String numarray[] = s.split(",");
    int odd[] = new int[20];
    int oddcnt=0;
    int even[] = new int[20];
    int evencnt =0;

    for(int i=0;i<numarray.length;i++)
    {

        if( Integer.parseInt((numarray[i]).trim())%2 ==0){
           odd[oddcnt] = Integer.parseInt(numarray[i].trim());
           oddcnt++;
        }

        {
            even[evencnt] = Integer.parseInt(numarray[i].trim());
            evencnt++;
        }
    }

    System.out.print("Odd Numbers : " );
        for (int i = 0; i < odd.length && odd[i] != 0; i++) {
            System.out.print(odd[i]+" " );
        }

        System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Even Numbers : " );
        for (int i = 0; i < even.length && even[i] != 0; i++) {
            System.out.print(even[i]+" " );
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is a more functional solution with less moving parts:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] split = in.nextLine().split(",");

    String evens = Arrays.stream(split)
            .filter(number -> Integer.parseInt(number) % 2 == 0)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

    String odds = Arrays.stream(split)
            .filter(number -> Integer.parseInt(number) % 2 != 0)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

    System.out.println("Even Numbers:\n" + evens);
    System.out.println("Odd Numbers:\n" + odds);
}
```

Yeah, it's quite inefficient, I know. There's probably a better way to do it, but I just wanted the OP to get a hint of how descriptive and simple a code can be.

Answer (score 0):

*a lambda with* `partitioningBy` *does the separation*
*it depends only on the last digit whether a string represents an even or odd number*
*a conversion into a numerical value is not necessary*

```
String inp = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
String[] nums = inp.split( "," );

Map<Boolean, List<String>> map = Arrays.stream( nums ).collect(
  partitioningBy(s -> "02468".indexOf(s.charAt(s.length() - 1)) >= 0));

System.err.println( "even: " + map.get( true ) );
System.err.println( "odd:  " + map.get( false ) );
```

`even: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]`
`odd:  [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]`